# Disallow access to tomcat's index.jsp to internet users

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web, tomcat7

I do not want internet users to access the tomcats index.jsp.

Say i have a domain as https://www.example.org. Then using https://www.example.org/index.jsp will show the tomcats manager to internet users too.

How can this be prevented ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using the [Tomcat's](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html) Remote Address Filter.

Modify the `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml`.

Add the filter like this:

```
<Context
    path="/manager"
    docBase="${catalina.home}/server/webapps"
    privileged="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
      allow="127\.0\.0\.1"
    />
</Context>
```

This will allow only local host addresses to access the manager app.